# How to draw in polar coordinates with P5.js?

Tags: javascript, processing, polar-coordinates, p5.js

There is a function [angleMode(mode);](http://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/angleMode) in P5 documentation that sets mode either RADIANS or DEGREES but I can't figure out how to use it or how to draw in polar coordinates in p5.js. Does anybody know how to do it with p5.js?

Comment: Can't you translate the polar coordinates to cartesian like `var x = r * cos(theta);` ? [from the ref.](https://p5js.org/examples/examples/Math_PolarToCartesian.php)

Answer (score 2):

`angleMode()` changes wheter p5.js interprets your angle values as radians and degrees. It has no impact on the way drawing is done.

You can just use trigonometric functions to translate between polar and cartesian.

```
var x = r * cos(angle)
var y = r * sin(angle)

point(x, y);
```

If you need more information, you can see this example in p5.js documentation: https://p5js.org/examples/math-polartocartesian.html

The coding train also has a video tutorial on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N633bLi_YCw

Answer (score 0):

`RADIANS` and `DEGREES` are the constants like 0 and 1. Therefore:

```
angleMode(DEGREES);// sets the mode
```

Comment: Yeah I got that, but how do I draw canvas element in polar coordinate. Does x become ϕ and y becomes r? ''

Comment: try call `angleMode(DEGREES)`, then ` ellipse(radius, alpha, width, height)`